# Does Routing in angular reload all the parent component as well?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In the base component I access header and footer selector along with it I have Routing module selector as well like this

`<app-header> </app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>`

Now if my router-outer redirect to some different path will angular reload the header and footer as well? or just the routing part will be loaded?

And what is the behavior if my routing take to a new TAB as in ctrl+click action on router.

Answer (score 0):

In case of the router navigating to a different route, header and footer will not reload.

In case the user opens the route in a new tab, the whole SPA will essentially reload. So yes, in that case, the header and footer will reload.